# "Preamble" menu item does not appear in LyX

Tags: lyx, xy-pic, preamble

I'm trying to use `xy-pic` in LyX to create diagrams and using [this](http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~gumm/LyX/xypic/xypic.pdf) tutorial. It says on page 3 to go Layout->Document->Preamble to enable the `xy-pic` package. However, there is no "Layout" menu on my LyX installation. There is a "Document" menu, but it doesn't contain any option "Preamble."

When I type `\xymatrix`, the command appears in the autocomplete list. However, when I type `\ar` within the `\xymatrix` context to create an arrow, it does not appear. `\ar` causes compile errors, and both `\ar` and `\xymatrix` cause compile errors when used in an evil red text context (between dollar signs) rather than a LyX math context.

I'm using LyX 2.0.1 on a Mac OSX Lion machine. This issue has been a problem in the past as well, but I haven't been able to find any information on it. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should [update your version of LyX to 2.0.4](http://www.lyx.org/Download). Then you can edit your preamble (*Document* > *Settings* > *LaTeX Preamble*) and include the text `\usepackage{xypic}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry if that was a stupid question, I just couldn't seem to find anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble and in there you can type `\usepackage[all]{xy}`

Note that it doesn't matter whether you have 2.0.4 or 2.0.1 for this particular point but you might as well upgrade.